# Format SQL table into HTML message (Not HTML table)?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

**SQL Table**

| Name | Missing |
| --- | --- |
| B | Jan |
| A | Jan |
| A | Mar |

**Desired Result**

```
A is missing Jan, Mar
B is missing Jan
```

How can I format the above sql table into the desired html? I have experience replicating this into an html table for sending out an email but not much else...

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but here is an option using `string_agg()`

```
with cte as (
Select Name,
       Missing = string_agg(missing,', ') 
 From  YourTable 
 Group By Name
)
Select string_agg(concat(Name,' is missing ',Missing),'<br>')
 From  cte
```

**Results**

```
A is missing Jan, Mar<br>B is missing Jan
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately I am running SQL 2016, it seems string_agg() may only be available in SQL 2017 and higher, but your answer led me to STUFF() which may give me the solution I'm looking for